# PHP не получает данные POST из input значение которой было добавлено через JS

Tags: php, javascript, html

имеется некая форма с input'ами, в 2 из них данные добавляются через JS автоматически остальный заполняются вручную. Самое инересное то, что именно из input'ов, в которые данные были добавлены автоматически POST не получает данные.

Форма:

```js
function setDate(year, day, month) {
   return document.getElementById('kp-form-line').value = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
  }

  function setTime(time) {
   switch(time) {
    case 1:
     return document.getElementById('ka-form-line').value = '11.00-13.30';
     break;
    case 2:
     return document.getElementById('ka-form-line').value = '14.30-17.00';
     break;
    case 3:
     return document.getElementById('ka-form-line').value = '18.00-20.30';
     break;
   }
  }
```

```html
<----- Кнопка которая вызывает функции ------>

<input type="button" class="m-bron" value="11:00-13:30 - Vaba" onclick=" setDate(2000, 31, 2); setTime(1);">

<--- Эти 3 переменные создаются в PHP коде и они выводятся нормально --->

<------ Форма ------->

<form action='/manage/broneer' method='POST' class='vorm' >
   <label for='kp-form-line'>
      <p id='bron-text'>Soovitud kuupäev</p>
   </label>
   <input type='text' id='kp-form-line' name='kp-form-line' required='required' aria-requried='true' pattern='[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}' disabled='disabled' value='22'><br>
   <label for='ka-form-line'>
      <p id='bron-text'>Soovitud kellaeg</p>
   </label>
   <input type='text' id='ka-form-line' required='required' aria-requried='true' pattern='[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}' name='ka-form-line' disabled='disabled'><br>
   <label for='ln-form-line'>
      <p id='bron-text'>Sünnipäevalapse nimi ja vanus</p>
   </label>
   <input type='text' id='ln-form-line' name='ln-form-line' required='required' aria-requried='true' placeholder='Näiteks - Adele, 8a.'><br>
   <label for='vn-form-line'>
      <p id='bron-text'>Teie nimi</p>
   </label>
   <input type='text' id='vn-form-line' name='vn-form-line' required='required' aria-requried='true' placeholder='Ees- ja perekonnanimi'><br>
   <label for='mail-form-line'>
      <p id='bron-text'>Teie Email</p>
   </label>
   <input type='email' id='mail-form-line' name='mail-form-line' required='required' aria-requried='true' placeholder='Email'><br>
   <label for='tel-form-line'>
      <p id='bron-text'>Teie Telefon</p>
   </label>
   <input type='tel' id='tel-form-line' name='tel-form-line' required='required' aria-requried='true' placeholder='Telefon' pattern='[0-9()#&+*-=.]+'><br>
   <label for='lis-form-line'>
      <p>Lisainfo (nt lisateenused jms)</p>
   </label>
   <textarea name='ta-form-line' class='ta-field' id='lis-form-line' cols='30' rows='3'></textarea>
   <label for='check-box'>
      <p class='bron-label'>BRONEERINGU KINNITAMISEL NÕUSTUN MÄNGUTOA MAGIALAND REEGLITEGA</p>
   </label>
   <input type='checkbox' name='chk-form-line' required='required' aria-required='true' id='check-box'>
   <p style='color:black; margin-top: 20px;'>Broneerimistasu on 40 EUR, mis arvestatakse maha sünnipäeva kogumaksumusest</p>
   <input type='submit' value='Saada broneering' name='enter'>
</form>
```

Первые 2 input'а не передают данные в POST.

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: а вы уверенны, что Js устанавливает эти значения?

Comment: Да, вы можете убедится запустив код.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался сам, input'ы с параметром disabled параматры в POST не передает.